# MySQL join on column with different data type caused block nested loop join

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following query

```sql
select  from table_a
left join table_b on table_a.id = table_b.id
```

the data types of the joined column: `table_a.id` int `table_b.id` is varchar.and I am mysql version is 8.0.17.
My question is how to avoid Block Nested Loop in this situation?

Comment: both id column have index created

Answer (score 0):

You can run the query with

```sql
set optimizer_switch='block_nested_loop=off'
```

Comment: Thx, however this seems don't help improve performance.